# How to pass jquery variables to php variable without url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to get jquery variable to php variable using Ajax. I would be very grateful if anyone can help me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#roomOptions select').change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('#roomOptions select').each(function() {
            total+=parseInt($(this).val());

        });
        $('#roomOptions #roomOptions_total').html(total);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean without url?

Comment: You can not do that without using ajax

Comment: FatalError Can you explain how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass some data from the client side to the server side, use AJAX, you can choose to send the data as GET or POST

```
$.ajax({
    url: full_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"x":1,"y":2}
    success: function(result)
    {
        // do somthing
    }
});
```

Comment: the variable result in the success function is what the php will send in the response.

Comment: In the php you can get the value of x with $_POST['x'], same goes for y. Now if you do in the php echo '12345'; exit;  the value of 12345 will pass to the result variable in the success function of the ajax

Comment: how to pass total variable to php in ajax?

Comment: data: {"total":total}

Comment: the value of the data is a json object, you can pass whatever you like in there

Comment: What can use for  success: function(result)
    {
        // do somthing
    }

Answer (score -1):

You clearly can't. PHP is executed first and then jQuery is executed.